# After 18h my app is not published, google play console

Tags: console, google-play, google-play-console

Hi I published my app about 18 hours ago and still writes me 'waiting for publication' and moreover every time I connect to google play console it gives me an error in red at the top with 'error 1000004'.
This morning I tried to create another release and send it as an update to restart sending, but still nothing 'awaiting publication'
In general, publication has always been very fast for my other apps.

Comment: Contact the [Google Play developer support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en).

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted ? We are having a nightmare at the moment with Google Play saying the app is released (v 2.0.1) AND at the same time it sits in "updating pending" which keeps resetting its 'start time' every few hours. Would love to know how you sorted this if poss.

Comment: Sort of the same problem here...except as near as I can tell the publish process is successful but after 28 hours no users have gotten updates/installs. "Chat" support is not available so I got in an email and Google responded with their commitment to respond within two days (not helpful).